# Laravel 5 htaccess on shared web. Works both with /public/ URL and without

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, public-html

I am using Laravel 5.4 on shared web hosting. Site is running fine, without any functional problems. I am forcing HTTPS + WWW always.

But there are issue with URL path after redirect from invalid/non-existing page.

Instead of `https://www.example.com/` in URL it shows `https://www.example.com/public/`

There are no redirect to `/public/` if I go to any existing pages. Site is working fine in both ways, with or without `/public/`. For visitors it could  be confusing that sometimes it is `/public/` in end of URL and sometimes it is without. For example, normally I have URL `https://www.example.com/about` , but it is also working in `https://www.example.com/public/about` In this case I am also not sure about possible vulnerabilities.

I have 2 .htaccess files, one in project root folder `public_html` and another inside Laravel public folder `public_html/public`.

1) **public_html/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

2) **public_html/public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(txt|xml)$ - [L]

# Force SSL + WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Make sure your vhost (if applicable) document root is the `/public` folder

Comment: @apokryfos I have SSH access, but I don't have access to edit virtual hosts.

Comment: Well do a redirect rewrite e.g. `^public/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]` or something like that. The disadvantage is you won't be able to register any route starting with `public` in the laravel router.